# wifi not detected in dell inspiron

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell

i have ubuntu 12.04 installed in my dell inspiron 15R laptop but the wifi is not enabled

i have tried some solutions but it has not worked till now

when i use the `lspci -vvv comand` i get

`08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0016`

```
`Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
Region 0: Memory at c1500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Capabilities: <access denied>`
```

the command `lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4` gave this output

`08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:4365] (rev 01)`

one of the threads also gave a .deb file to install which gave me an error though i am unable to locate that thread now

i have tried installing and uninstalling  `b43-fwcutter`
ando also installing and uninstalling

`sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source`

`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

dosent seem to work

`gksu jockey-gtk` also doesn't show any options regarding wifi

i seem to have tried a lot of things and havent kept track so so i dont know the present status of my system :(

i do not know how to use ndiswrapper.

how can i get my wifi working? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try additional drivers, aka jockey? It worked for my broadcom once.

Comment: Can you edit your answer with the steps required please? It needs more information to be helpful to most users.

Comment: yes i have tried it, it only shows 2 entries corresponding to my ati graphics chipset.

Comment: it dosent show any entries regarding wifi drivers.

Comment: I assume you were connected to the internet via ethernet when you checked.